# Vaadin update combobox values in a grid

Tags: java, web-applications, combobox, vaadin

I have a Vaadin (7.6.7) grid, that shows a combobox when in editor mode. Another action can modify the items of the combobox, but the combobox in the grid does not update itself.

```
public void setComboBoxAsEditor(Grid grid) {
  grid.getColumn("id").setEditorField(theBox).setConverter(new Converter<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String convertToModel(String value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        return value; // not sure for what this is required
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToPresentation(String value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        // don't show the id, but the name
        A a = endpoint.getA(value);
        return a.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getModelType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getPresentationType() {
        return String.class;
    }
 });
}
```

`theBox` is a Combobox that is filled before - the initial display is correct (it contains objects of type `A`)

Now another action manipulates the objects of type `A`, e.g. delete an object.

How can I update now the combobox in the grid ?

I tried

```
public void upateCombobox() {
 theBox.removeAllItems();
 List<A> as = endpoint.getAs();
 theBox.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(String.class, as.stream().map(A::getIdent).collect(Collectors.toList())));
 for (A each : as) {
    theBox.setItemCaption(a.getId(), a.getName());
 }
}
```

to call before, but when editing the grid, the `theBox` shows still the old values.

I tried to call `grid.getColumn("id").getEditorField().markAsDirty()`, but also no change

What do I miss ?

Comment: Your converter method `convertToModel` doesn't make sense I think. It is called when writing to the "id" column. It should map the `A.getName()` back to the model. However, this shouldn't effect the behavior that is your problem. Maybe you have a typo. You set the container data source to `teamBox` instead of `theBox`?

Comment: About `convertToModel` - it seems to work without anything there and also it seems not to be called at all (?). And yes, there was a typo. `theBox` is the `Combobox` and on this I update the items.

Comment: When adding `theBox.getContainerDataSource().getItemIds().forEach(System.out::println);` in the update method i have, that `theBox` has correctly the right objects, it is only the UI that does not get updated

Comment: **1** Just tried locally and adding, removing, clearing works flawlessly for me, even when the editor was active. The only thing I wasn't aware at first is that when I added an item, it was not visible because it was position at the end, so I had to scroll the combo-box. Can you share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) on github or similar? **2** You can replace the `for (A each : as) {theBox.setItemCaption(a.getId(), a.getName());` with `theBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");`

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer.

My update method looked like this

```
public void update() {
   updateCombobox();
}
```

Now it looks like this

```
public void update() {
    createCombobox(); // this creates a new reference to theBox
    setComboboxAsEditor(); 
}
```

So, I create new instance of `theBox` and fill it with the data in `updateCombobox`, then setting this as a new editorfield for the column.

Not sure about the rightness of it, but it works